# Open a file name +date as csv in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, file-io, xls

I want to be able to open a file name automatically and save it as a .csv, the files I produce are always called the same thing + todays date. For example todays spreadsheet could be called:

```
"TODAYS SHEET" + Todays date.xls
```

Stored in location

```
C:\A\B\C\D
```

How would I get the code to open todays .xls file and save it as a .csv in location

```
C:\A\B\C\D\E
```

I ultimately want to load data directly from this .csv file for comparison with a webscraper, so there may well be a method to open a .xls file as a .csv without saving it as a .csv in a second location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should look like something close to that:

```
import datetime
today_string = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%x')

with open('C:/A/B/C/D/TODAYS SHEET' + today_string + '.csv', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write('a,a,a,a,a,a')
```

You can have a look at the [string format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the strftime function. Also have a look at the [open function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) and what you can do [with files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: cheers Paco, does the above code open a .xls directly as a .csv ?

Comment: a CSV, if you want a xls, you'll need to work with the python excel modules http://www.python-excel.org/

Answer (score 1):

To open the csv i would use xlrd.

```
import csv
import datetime
import os

import xlrd

path = "C:\Users\John\Desktop"
file_name = "TODAYS SHEET " + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ".csv"

with open(os.path.join(path, file_name), 'w') as file_:

    writer = csv.writer(file_)

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('herp.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('A Snazzy Title')

    num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
    curr_row = -1

    while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1
        row = [cell.value for cell in worksheet.row(curr_row)]
        writer.writerow(row)
```